# Is it necessary to install `node-jsx` if we use reactify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify, reactify

In my Nodejs application, I use React. I browserify + reactify to transform `.jsx` files to `js` files. 
I use this line of code in my entry `js` file :

```
require('node-jsx').install();
```

I noticed that `node-jsx` is deprecated. Do I still need to have this line if I already reactify my react files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to use either `node-jsx` or JSXTransformer when using reactify. Reactify does all the transforms needed.

Most likely the reason `node-jsx` is deprecated is because it is a very bad idea to compile at runtime, as the browser has to download the entire compiler and the compiler will take time to load. Always pre-compile JSX, babel, and coffeescript.

Comment: But another problem is happening now : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062871/getting-rid-of-node-jsx