# Getting rid of node-jsx

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In the router of my NodeJS app, I want to render a react app. As it is not browserified (and there reactified) it returns `unexpected token <` error while building. I found if I `require("node-jsx").install()` it doesn't return me this error. 
But `node-jsx` is deprecated. Is there any way to build the project without requiring it ?

```
var JSX = require('node-jsx').install(),//as we don't reactify it while building
    React = require('react'),
    Board = React.createFactory(require('../components/board')),
    DataStore = require('../store/store');


    var router = require('express').Router();

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        var initialState = {'users': DataStore.getUsers()};
        var markup = React.renderToString(
            Board(initialState)
        );
        res.render('board', {
            markup: markup,
            state: JSON.stringify(initialState),
            layout: 'boardLayout'
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If your board component is in jsx, it needs to be transformed to js before it can be rendered by react. Is board a jsx file?

Comment: Yes, actually it is a jsx file , but with a `.js` extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node-jsx has been deprecated in favor of [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/). Instead of `require('node-jsx').install();`, you can now use`require('babel-register');`.

Comment: Back in 2015 (when the original answer was written), `babel/register` was correct.  The APIs have obviously been updated since then, and I have updated my answer.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: sorry for the shouting part, I was with a friend, and it was a inside joke. lol

Answer (score 1):

Since babel 6 above answer will not work. Please use babel-register instead.

It is recommend that you don't use this setup in production. For production you should trans-pile all the files and use something in lines of node server.js.